# Adding Session / Array to SQL Database

Tags: php, sql

I have the session created and it stores the data, that is working 100%;

I have a foreach loop that converts all the session data into an array of in_fields and in_values.

But the form is not submitting to the database, please assist !

```
    // sql fields and values
$in_fields = array();
$in_values = array();


foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
        $value = sql_escape($value);
        $key = explode("#",$key);

            $in_fields[] = "`{$key[0]}`";
            $in_values[] = "'{$value}'";
    }
}

if(!empty($in_fields)) {

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO wills(";
    $sql .= implode(", ",$in_fields);
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    $sql .= implode(", ",$in_values);
    $sql .= ")";

if(executeSql($sql)) {
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
                executeSql($sql);
            }
        }
```

I have created a print_r of $in_fields and $in_values and it displays as an array.

The error i am receiving now:

```
Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in E:\xampp\htdocs\sc\form\inc\functions.php on line 22
```

Database query error.
Unknown column 'step' in 'field list'

LIne 22 from Functions.php

```
    $value = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($value) : trim($value);
```

Comment: why are you looping the session array, why not just use Serialize - http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: what about printing query itself?

Comment: you see no SQL query in your code?

Comment: printing out sql error will do a little help too. what SQL software it is?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel i get the following:

`INSERT INTO wills(`selection`, `first_name`, `age`, `step`) VALUES ('1st_Marriage', 'John', '18', '') `

Comment: Are you connecting successfully to the database and capable of executing other queries against that same table? What does the call to the database look like (probably the next line in your code)?

Comment: @Bob it works fine with other queries

Comment: @Bob updated the code above with the call to the DB i seem to get a new error now which i will add above too now

Comment: @Lawrence it is called "user defined functions". a feature

Comment: @all i got it to work now it was because i had to unset "step" from my session data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Database query error. Unknown column 'step' in 'field list'

do you need any further explanations?

Comment: @all i got it to work now it was because i had to unset "step" from my session data